# how to delete and append in a list python

Tags: python

This is my code

```
    k = []
    dot = input('length:')
    a, b = input('Enter:')
    for i in range(0,dot):
        k.append('.')

    for i in range(a, b+1):
        k[i].append('x')

    print k
```

when i try to run this the output will be like,

```
length:9
Enter:3, 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "light_switch.py", line 8, in <module>
    k[i].append('x')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

i want to insert a 'x' in the the place of '.'. so how do i do it.

Comment: Your error includes `k[i].append('x')`, but your provided code does not. What is your actual code?

Comment: i included my actual code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace the `'.'` in the second range with `'x'`, just do:

```
for i in range(a, b+1):
    k[i] = 'x'
```

The error is because when you index to `k[i]` you get the `str` you put there, only `k` is a `list`, but the values are `str`. `str`, being immutable, lacks an `append` method (and since you say you want to replace, not concatenate, you wouldn't want an `append`-like operation anyway). If you wanted `append`-like behavior to each `'.'`, you'd change `k[i].append('x')` to `k[i] += 'x'` (which is logically constructing a new concatenated `str` and assigning it back, rather than mutating in place), or to add a whole bunch of `x`s to the end of the `list`, you'd just do `k.append('x')`.

Note: If `a < 0` or `b+1 > dot`, this will raise an `IndexError`; the former is unfixable, the latter could be handled in a kludgy way by simply making the first `for` loop run over `range(max(dot, b+1))` instead of `range(dot)`.

Answer (score 0):

To replace the dot with x you can try this code:

```
k = []
dot = input('length:')
a, b = input('Enter:')
for i in range(0,dot):
     k.append('.')

for i in range(a, b+1):
    k[i] = 'x'

print k
```

You already have a '.' at the location you are trying to add x so you just need to assign x instead of '.'. Location you are trying to access using a[j].append('x') is not a list and you are trying yo append x to it. So it is giving error.